# 2000 Suzuki Grand Vitara 4x4 flashing

Tags: electrical, suzuki, grand-vitara

Whenever i engage my 4x4, the 4x4 light flashes. It didn't used to do this. Its annoying watching it flash. Any ideas what could be causing it to flash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your 4x4 system uses air/vacuum power to engage the 4x4 system.  The flashing 4x4 light indicates a leak has been detected in the system.  Depending on the severity of the leak, the 4x4 system might not be fully functional and wheels may intermittently slip, or not lock at all.

There is a pump located behind the front bumper that maintains pressure in the system.  The flashing light could be caused by anything from a bad pump to a small leak in an air/vacuum hose.

Comment: Im pretty sure the wheels slip, it also makes clunking noise when i try going in reverse with 4x4 on. I looked at my axles and they slide side to side like they arent locking correctly. It might be that my cv joint is worn down.

Comment: Yes, the vacuum is needed to lock the auto-hubs, so slipping wheels is expected if there is a leak.  The fact that the system works at all probably means the pump is ok, so you should find the pump and associated hoses and start looking/listening for a leak.